# Template Argument Deduction with different typename

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I have defined a generic function like this:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
T2 Calculation(T1 arg_one, T1 arg_two)
{
    return arg_one + arg_two * 3.14;
}
```

When I try to use this generic function as follow:

```
auto sum = Calculation(2, 3.2);
```

Compiler told me: no matching overloaded function found. However, when I try to use this generic function like `Calculation<double, double>`, it works fine.

Why compiler couldn't deduce the type of the argument and return value in first sample? I have to explicitly define types?

Comment: What type should it deduce, `int` or `double`? Why?

Comment: Change `T1 arg_two` to `T2 arg_two`. A typo?

Comment: Double for return value and arguments.

Comment: I wanted return value and arguments are different from each other. for example i wanted to pass float value to this function and then get back a double.

Comment: You are not using `T2` inside the function so what you want is of no use. If you really want a different "return type" then simply use a deduced return type and cast the result after the call.

Comment: `2` is an `int`, `3.2` is a `double`, but your template says that both arguments should have the same type.

Comment: Side note: "generic function" is not something that exists in C++. That's a function template, and every instantiation of it is even more *specific* than a non-template function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **problem** is that `T2` cannot be deduced from any of the function parameters and `T2` also doesn't have any default argument, and template parameters can't be deduced from return type.

To **solve** this either you can either explicitly specify the template argument for `T2` when calling the function  or change `T1 arg_two` to `T2 arg_two` so that `T2` can also be deduced just like `T1` as shown below:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
//-------------------------vv---------->changed T1 to T2 so that T2 can be deduced from passed second argument
T2 Calculation(T1 arg_one, T2 arg_two)
{
    return arg_one + arg_two * 3.14;
}

auto sum = Calculation(2, 3.2); //works now
```

Answer (score 0):

This template code has return type bound to second argument type.

Please, consider more generic approach to deduce return type:

```
auto Calculation(auto arg_one, auto arg_two)
{
    return arg_one + arg_two * 3.14;
}
```